# Server Error in ‘/MobileAdmin’ Application

Tags: exchange-2003, .net, activesync, android

I posted this over at StackOverflow, but it appears it is more appropriate here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523089/server-error-in-mobileadmin-application

I have recently hooked up an Android device to Exchange 2003 via ActiceSync, and the MobileAdmin application (https://server/mobileadmin) crashes when I lookup a mailbox that is associated with an ActiveSync device. When I look up a mailbox that is not associated with a mailbox, it simply replies "No devices were found for this mailbox." I have scoured the search engines and forums, as well as followed the instructions located in the following KB to no avail.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916960

3 devices (Droid, Droid X, and Droid 2) are sending/receiving mail properly, I am simply unable to access the MobileAdmin web application that shows the device and mailbox association, and allows you to issue remote wipe commands.

Error report follows:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Admin.Mailbox.propFindRequest(String deviceUri) +391
   Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Admin.Mailbox.getDevices() +372
   Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Admin.Devices.refreshDevicesTable() +138
   Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Admin.Devices.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +750




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2443; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2460
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1) The MobileAdmin query was making DNS requests for “mail.yourdomain.com” on the external IP of the firewall instead of internally resolving the server name “INTERNAL_SERVERNAME”.

This problem was resolved by adding 127.0.0.1 "mail.yourdomain.com" to the local server’s HOST file so it will not make any DNS queries outside of the local environment.

2) The IIS configuration had a Host Name set when that should be blank.   The hostname was removed using the command:

C:\inetpub\admscripts> cscript adsutil.vbs delete w3svc/1/SetHostName